# Shiny R not reading custom CSS file

Tags: css, r, shiny, themes

I am able to use shiny's custom themes successfully, i.e.

```
# Internal, hidden function
# Called by CherryPickPalette()
CustomPal <- function(new_pal){
  if (interactive()){
    cherrypickedpalette <- runApp(list(
      ui = fluidPage(
        theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("slate"),
```

Will give app the following look and feel

[image]

However if I replace with custom .css, the program ignores it, i.e.

Custom CSS, **h5.css**

```
h5 {
color: orange;
text-align: center;
}
```

Code using **h5.css**

```
# Internal, hidden function
# Called by CherryPickPalette()
CustomPal <- function(new_pal){
  if (interactive()){
    cherrypickedpalette <- runApp(list(
      ui = fluidPage(
        theme = "h5.css",
        titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
        sidebarPanel (hr(),
                      selectInput('col', 'Options', new_pal, multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE, size = 15)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          h5('Your Cherry-Picked Palette'),
          fluidRow(column(12,verbatimTextOutput("col"))),
```

h5 text, i.e. "Your Cherry-Picked Palette" is unaffected.

R directory structure is [here](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/tree/master/R)

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure why it does not work with this directory structure, but you can try that instead:

```
ui = fluidPage(
       # theme = "h5.css",
       tags$head(includeCSS("R/www/h5.css")),
       titlePanel("Cherry Pick Your Own Palette!"),
       ...
)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try with the absolute path. Where are you running it from? I cloned your repo and I was able to run it with the CSS using `includeCSS`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Only if I hard-code, then it works, but it's best practice to use separate css sheet. Will tinker with code. BTW, when I saved txt file as css, it is encoded as UFT-8, if that is relevant.

Comment: I uninstalled entire R on another computer, reinstalled, and then cloned my repository. Unfortunately, still not working.

Comment: It seems .css has to be ANSI encoding. And `tags$head(includeCSS("R/www/h5.css")),` will work rather than `tags$head(includeCSS("h5.css"))`